# HOW TO TRAVERSE TWO VECTORS IN A SINGLE LOOP

Tags: c++, loops, vector, c++14, traversal

Suppose I have a vector a=[2 4 6 8 9] and a vector b=[1 5 1 8 7]
So How I Can Traverse both the vector in a single loop like suppose

vector :: iterator it=a.begin();

for(vector  :: iterator it1= b. begin(); it1 != b. end(); ++it1;++it)

is it correct way to use so?

Comment: If both vectors have the same size, you can iterate using *indexes* instead of iterators. Otherwise, it really depends on your use-case, and the problem you're actually trying to solve with this loop ([related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)).

Comment: Also please don't write in all upper-case. It's considered shouting, and shouting is rude. Lastly please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and please learn how to [edit] your question and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`boost::combine`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/combine.html) or [`range::views::zip`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#autotoc_md8) to get a range-for loop over both.

```
for (auto & [fromA, fromB] : boost::combine(a, b))
```

Absent a library function like that, I'd tidy your definitions

```
for(auto it = a.begin(), it1 = b.begin(); it1 != b.end(); ++it1,++it)
```

If you don't know if `a` and `b` are the same size, you should be more careful

```
for(auto it = a.begin(), it1 = b.begin(); it != a.end() && it1 != b.end(); ++it1,++it)
```

Answer (score 0):

to traverse two vector in a single loop its mandatory that both the vector has same size
if two vectors are vect1 & vect2
then vect1.size()==vect2.size()
so to traverse
for(auto i=vect1.begin();i<vect1.end();i++)
now traverse both by taking i as index